# Separate Archiva configuration and installation directories

Tags: configuration, directory, installation, archiva

The Archiva documentation states:

> The standalone installation of Archiva is capable of separating its configuration from installation

However, I didn't manage to do so with 1.3.6 and 1.4 (using Ubuntu 12.04).

`$ARCHIVA_BASE` is set to `/var/archiva` and exported, but the wrapper doesn't seem to take care of that and always launches in the installation directory.

Moreover, the 1.4 init script (bin/archiva) uses `$BASEDIR` instead of `$ARCHIVA_BASE`

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: This certainly works in Archiva 1.3.6 (see https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-archiva for an example that configures it that way). More info would be needed on the error. For 1.4, that does seem like a regression that needs to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post is old but I faced this problem recently and wanted to share what worked for me to make Archiva 2.2.3 execute as a service on RHEL 6.8

- Archiva installed at `/opt/archiva`
- Archiva data directory created at `/var/archiva_data` using [these](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/adminguide/standalone.html) instructions
- Edited `/opt/archiva/conf/wrapper.conf` and made the following change

  ```
  set.default.ARCHIVA_BASE=/var/archiva_data
  ```
- Edited `/opt/archiva/bin/archiva` and made the following change

  ```
  RUN_AS_USER=foo
  ```
- Linked `/etc/init.d/archiva` with `/opt/archiva/bin/archiva`
- Start service using `service archiva start`

Answer (score 1):

How I do personally.
My archiva app installed in /x1/archiva/archiva with 
archiva -> /x1/archiva/apache-archiva-1.4-M4-SNAPSHOT

And all datas archiva.xml in /x1/archiva/archiva-base

archiva start script is modified with:

BASEDIR=/x1/archiva/archiva/bin

BASEDIR_CONF="/x1/archiva/archiva-base"

WRAPPER_CONF="$BASEDIR_CONF/conf/wrapper.conf"

PIDDIR="$BASEDIR_CONF/logs"

And it works fine as it :-)

Answer (score 1):

This post might be a little old, I'd nonetheless like to share my experience using Archiva 2.2.1. Seperating the base from the installation directory by simply setting `$ARCHIVA_BASE` (as described on http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/standalone.html) still doesn't work. I did the following to get Archiva up and running:

**My setup**

- Archiva binaries and installation files in */opt/archiva/current*
  (*current* being a symlink pointing to *apache-archiva-2.2.1*)
- Directories *conf/ data/ logs/ temp/* moved to */data/archiva_data*

**Adjustments in Archiva config files**

File */opt/archiva/current/bin*:

```
BASEDIR_CONFIG="/data/archiva_data"
WRAPPER_CONF="$BASEDIR_CONFIG/conf/wrapper.conf"
PIDDIR="$BASEDIR_CONFIG/logs"
```

Wrapper config File */data/archiva_data/conf/wrapper.conf*:

```
#Manually set the Archiva Basedir
set.default.ARCHIVA_BASE=/data/archiva_data
```

So the steps pointed out by [olamy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261734/olamy) did work, however a further adjustment was needed in the wrapper config file to reflect the configuration being moved away from the installation directory.

After the changes, I was able to start and use Archiva.

Answer (score 0):

1 remember to use cp when you copy configuration files from original conf folder to your folder.

2 if you're trying to run archiva as service you need to modify wrapper.conf at line 14 with added your ARCHIVA_BASE folder.